# Returning to JFrame from JOptionPane

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I'm making a simple text editor in Java using a JFrame and JtextAreas etc... When I click an exit button, I create a new JOptionPane and it asks the user whether it wants to save and exit, or cancel and keep typing. I have no idea how to delete the JOptionPane, however, and return to the text editor. I've googled around and I can't find anything!
Here's some code:

```
exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Save and Exit?", "Exit" ,JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            switch(reply){
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });
    file.add(exit);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have no idea how to delete the JOptionPane, however, and return to the text editor.

??

I'm not sure I understand your problem as this is done automatically when the JOptionPane OK or Cancel buttons are pressed or if the jOptionPane is canceled by pressing the right upper corner button.

Comment: Oh, sorry I had an extra system.exit floating around that was closing the program... sorry guys :/